# IE - checking checkbox on image click

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've found a strange behavior in IE. When HTML code inside `<form>` tag it won't work.

```
<div>
    <label>
        <img src="media/afternoon-1.jpg" alt="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="afternoon[]" value="1" />
    </label>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SiZE/nss7qz85/

Have test it in IE 11.0.9600.17842

Is it possible to fix it without JS?

Comment: Working fine in IE9 & IE10.

Comment: I have no older IE, thanks for testing. I've temporrary fix it with JS code. `$(document).on('click','label[for]',function(e){ $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).trigger('click');
});`